Reusing text for grants
I am currently submitting a few small non-federal grants to private companies and foundations (think tech companies like Google etc.). Am I allowed to reuse text and submit highly similar proposals to these entities concurrently? I have not found any submissions guidelines banning this practice (I understand this is not acceptable in the context of federal grants).

Do you apply for the same project in parallel? I think that is an important consideration.

I see no ethical reasons that would argue against being able to re-use text. Obviously, you want to make sure that every application is targeted to the specific opportunity you are applying for, but that does not exclude the possibility that you re-use some text.
(In fact, I also don't see a specific problem doing the same when applying for federal grants.)

Good advice. Just make sure the projects are different enough that if you get multiple funded then they are for different projects.

A very reasonable question! Comparing to journal submissions, right, simultaneous submissions "bad", for various good reasons.
Similarly, NSF and some related funding agencies do not want a simultaneous submission of "the same project". Yes, there is an issue about what "the same project" might mean.
While I do think that this is an intellectually silly concept, I can see that it may be "necessary" from an administrative viewpoint. Sigh.
Operationally, as others have said, the only way to know what is administratively acceptable is to read the rules...
